# How to set seed the LSTM Model

Tags: python, numpy, keras, lstm

I would like to know whether anyone knows how to set seed the LSTM model so that we can get the reproducible model? In this case, my MSE and RMSE always changes over and over every time when I ran the code.

So far, my code is such the follows:

```
######################################################################################
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'

# Setting the seed for numpy-generated random numbers
np.random.seed(37)

# Setting the seed for python random numbers
rn.seed(1254)

# Setting the graph-level random seed.
tf.random.set_seed(89)

from keras import backend as K

session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
      intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
      inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

#Force Tensorflow to use a single thread
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)

tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
######################################################################################

# define model
#reset_seeds()
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# fit model
#reset_seeds()
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=0, shuffle=False)
model.reset_states()

#reset_seeds()
yhat = model.predict(X, verbose=0)

m = yhat.shape[0]
print("MSE: ", (1/m) * np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(y, yhat))))

print("RMSE: ", np.sqrt((1/m) * np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(y, yhat)))))
```

I have followed many guidelines on google but I just couldn't find one which works to get the my LSTM model reproducible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a difference between the weights of a LSTM (the usual parameter set of a ANN), which are by default also initialized by the Glorot or also known as the Xavier initializer (as mentioned in the question).

A different aspect is the cell state and the state of the initial recurrent input to the LSTM. Those are initialized by a matrix usually denoted as `initial_state`.

Leaving us with the question, how to initialize this `initial_state`:

> 1. Zero State Initialization is good practice if the impact of initialization is low

The default approach to initializing the state of an RNN is to use a zero state. This often works well, particularly for sequence-to-sequence tasks like language modeling where the proportion of outputs that are significantly impacted by the initial state is small.

> 2. Zero State Initialization in each batch can lead to overfitting

Zero Initialization for each batch will lead to the following: Losses at the early steps of a sequence-to-sequence model (i.e., those immediately after a state reset) will be larger than those at later steps, because there is less history. Thus, their contribution to the gradient during learning will be relatively higher. But if all state resets are associated with a zero-state, the model can (and will) learn how to compensate for precisely this. As the ratio of state resets to total observations increases, the model parameters will become increasingly tuned to this zero state, which may affect performance on later time steps.

> 3. Do we have other options?

One simple solution is to make the initial state noisy (to decrease the loss for the first time step). Look here for [details and other ideas](http://www.scs-europe.net/conf/ecms2015/invited/Contribution_Zimmermann_Grothmann_Tietz.pdf)